# Why won't my socket.io events work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, connection, socket.io

I'm writing an express app that uses socket.io; however all I'm getting is the sever side telling me I'm connected, aside from that, none of my sockets are working.  If anyone can tell as to why this is happening that would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code for client and server below:

Client:

```
var socket = new io.Socket();
socket.connect('127.0.0.1:3000');
var pageView = new pageViewModel();
pageView.setCurrentPage(pageView.getLogin());
pageView.setNav(pageView.getLogNav());
var tView = new totalViewModel();
socket.on('connection', function () {
  ko.applyBindings(pageView);

  function loggedIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var logged = {
      username: document.getElementById('pEmail').value,
      password: document.getElementById('pWord').value
    };
    socket.emit('login', JSONout(logged));
    alert(JSONout(logged));
  }

  function signUp() {
    pageView.setCurrentPage(pageView.getRegister());
    pageView.setNav(pageView.getRegisterNav());
    ko.applyBindings(pageView);
  }
  socket.on('uploadList', function (data) {
    pageView.setCurrentPage(pageView.getIndex());
    pageView.setNav(pageView.getIndexNav());
    ko.applyBindings(pageView);
    tView.setNum(JSONin(data).total);
    ko.applyBindings(tView);
  });

  function logPurchase(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var purchObj = {
      price: document.getElementById('pPrice').value,
      priceName: document.getElementById('pName').value,
      entryDate: new Date()
    };
    socket.emit('purchaseLog', JSONout(purchObj));
  }

  function logDeposit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var depositObj = {
      price: document.getElementById('dPrice').value,
      entryDate: new Date()
    };
    socket.emit('depositLog', JSONout(purchObj));
  }

  function getLogout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pageView.setCurrentPage(pageView.getLogin());
    pageView.setNav(pageView.getLogNav());
    ko.applyBindings(pageView);
    socket.emit('goLogout', {
      none: 'none'
    });
  }

  function getIndex(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pageView.setCurrentPage(pageView.getIndex());
    pageView.setNav(pageView.getIndexNav());
    ko.applyBindings(pageView);
  }

  function getMonthly(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pageView.setCurrentPage(pageView.getMonthly());
    pageView.setNav(pageView.getMonthlyNav());
    ko.applyBindings(pageView);
  }

  function getYearly(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pageView.setCurrentPage(pageView.getYearly());
    pageView.setNav(pageView.getYearlyNav());
    ko.applyBindings(pageView);
  }
  socket.on('wentMonth', function (data) {
    tView.setNum(total in JSONin(data));
    ko.applyBindings(tView);
  });
  socket.on('wentYearly', function (data) {
    tView.setNum(total in JSONin(data));
    ko.applyBindings(tView);
  });

  function register(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var reg = {
      username: document.getElementById('pEmail').value,
      password: document.getElementById('pWord').value,
      dateJoined: new Date(),
      total: 0,
      purchase: {},
      deposit: {},
      monthlyTotal: 0,
      yearlyTotal: 0
    };
    pageView.setCurrentPage(pageView.getIndex());
    pageView.setNav(pageView.getIndexNav());
    ko.applyBindings(pageView);
    socket.emit('registered', JSONout(reg));
  }
});
```

Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var http = require('http');
var db = mongojs('127.0.0.1:27017/mySpendingDB', ['users']);
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var path = require('path');
app.configure(function () {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('mainPage.html', {
    title: 'app'
  });
});
var user = "";
db.users.find(function (err, docs) {
  console.log(docs);
  return docs;
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('socket.io started');
  socket.on('login', function (data) {
    console.log('login');
    var checkUser = db.users.find(data, function (err, docs) {
      return docs;
    });
    console.log(checkUser);
    if (checkUser !== null) {
      console.log('checked user');
      user = checkUser.username;
      socket.emit('uploadList', checkUser.total);
    } else {
      console.log('Log in invalid');
    }
  });
  socket.on('purchaseLog', function (data) {
    var usercollection = db.users.find({
      username: user
    });
    usercollection.purchase.save(data);
  });
  socket.on('depositLog', function (data) {
    var usercollection = db.users.find({
      username: user
    });
    usercollection.deposit.save(data);
  });
  socket.on('goMonthly', function (data) {
    var monTot = db.users.find({
      username: user
    }).monthlyTotal;
    socket.emit('wentMonthly', monTot);
  });
  socket.on('goYearly', function (data) {
    var yearTot = db.users.find({
      username: user
    }).yearlyTotal;
    socket.emit('wentYearly', yearTot);
  });
  socket.on('registered', function (data) {
    db.users.save(data);
  });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: can you define "not working"? Are you seeing the events on the server, but not back up at the client? Are you seeing nothing in the server at all except connections? Are you seeing errors in the client?

Comment: All I'm seeing are connections on the server.